# Custom code to read and write physical address memory on linux

Tags: c, linux, memory

I have try to access physical memory directly. I found that there is a tool in /usr/bin/devmem2. So I copy the code of devmem2.c, with simple compile command:g++ devmem2.c -o test. but later, I found that /usr/bin/devmem2 can read and write successful, but the binary test I had compiled can only read.
Any idea?

Comment: Could be a permissions issue. What happens? Do you get an error? Are you running the commands in the same way?

Comment: Yes,I run them in the same way.0 error when compiled and no memory error occur on runtime.(run command: devmem2 0x4a0f6000 w 0x10000000).I have think that may be a permissions issue,but I always run as root.

Comment: Did you try modifying same address to same value with both programs? Some addresses might not be modifiable even by root. Also if you modify some random address you could screw up your running code or operating system, so in that case all bets are off.

Comment: Oh..you are right. Some address is modifiable.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, the problem is unrelated to the build. You have to only write to memory which is modifiable. Even as root, you cannot modify certain memory addresses.

Comment: That is right.But why does devmem2(/usr/bin/devmem2) can write the memory that my own process can't?It still confuse me.